# what does /= do in the c++ example below?

Tags: c++, boost

Example:

```
boost::filesystem::path filename;
filename /= boost::filesystem::temp_directory_path();
filename /= boost::filesystem::unique_path();
```

Is it better than?

`auto filename = boost::filesystem::unique_path("%%%%-%%%%-%%%%-%%%%");`

Comment: C++ lets you divide strings by strings? What does it do?

Comment: They are obviously not strings. Operator overloading. Read the expletive documentation.

Comment: Poor choice for operator overloading, in my view.

Comment: Very poor choice.  For shame boost.

Comment: The operator looks like the path separator, on that side it looks fine. IMHO unless there's something wrong semantically, e.g. wrong operator precedence I think you're merely expressing your tastes and biases.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, first of, it looks like path separator **on linux**. Windows have a different one. Second, it doesn't work well with '+'. Third, one could expect it to do the opposite of '*' - while in fact it does not. Overall, it violates the semantics of built-in operator, and I do not welcome that.

Comment: @SergeyA That poor choice seems to be in its way to the standard ([File System TS](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/P0218r1.html#path-appends)). I suppose you always have the choice to call `append` explicitly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

boost::filesystem is overloading the /= operator to call the append method of the path object, "filename" in this case.

According to the [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#path-appends):

> *Effects:*
>
> Appends path::preferred_separator to pathname, converting format and
>   encoding if required ([path.arg.convert]), unless:
>
> - an added separator would be redundant, or
> - would change an relative path to an absolute path, or
> - p.empty(), or
> - *p.native().cbegin() is a directory separator.
>
> Then appends p.native() to pathname.
>
> *Returns:* *this

The two snippets are not equivalent, so they can't be compared for relative stylistic merit.

Comment: Appreciate the reference to the docs.  Not able to vote, otherwise +1.